# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis during Date Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle19c

Am using the below query but it gives an error. With other tables, it works fine.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(DZ_BEGINN DEFAULT NULL ON conversion error
        ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS MIN
FROM V_IPSL_PPE_OXF_AZEIT;
```

Error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
> ORA-02063: preceding line from L_IPSL_PPE_OXF 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: I suppose it's `AS MIN`. `MIN` is a reserved word. The DBMS expects parentheses and a parameter for the `MIN` function.

Comment: Working as expected in 18c.. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5044bc60fb77ced4e70448a59cf2d03f

Comment: @ThorstenKettner .  . The `as min` works when I try it.  My suspicion is that you have a hidden character of some sort.

Comment: I don't think Oracle has MIN as reservered, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: Error shows at `L_IPSL_PPE_OXF` . Please share your entire query.

Comment: @Popeye L_IPSL_PPE_OXF is part of my view name (V_IPSL_PPE_OXF_AZEIT) which mentioned in the query. Though am not sure what is the reason behind this. But this is the only query am running.

Comment: So there must be issue with view query.

Comment: Except MIN column name,  `DEFAULT NULL ON conversion error` is a 12.2 feature.

Comment: @leftjoin am using oracle 19c version. Also removing MIN from my query gives same error.

Comment: I've just tried the query on Oracle 19c and don't get an error.

Comment: Yeah, this is data issue.. but not sure for which type of data and how to handle this?

Comment: I am sure this is not a data issue. ORA-00907 is a syntax error not a runtime error. Maybe just a typo. Delete the lines and write them from scratch and the error may be gone.

Comment: I already tried this trick, but of no luck. If i change the table name it just works fine. In addition to missing parenthesis error am getting - ORA-02063: preceding line from L_IPSL_PPE_ROS. Not sure if this could be the reason and how to fix.

Comment: Try substituting the View definition for the View name in your SQL and run that. It may give you a better idea if where the problem is

Comment: As the query is syntactically correct and you are getting a syntax error nonetheless, this looks like an issue with SQL created at runtime. Does your view include a PL/SQL function that executes dynamic SQL?